# In S3, is there a way to deny bucket owner accessing object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Firstly, what is the difference between these two ACL options: private/bucket-owner-full-control? From document, one is FULL_CONTROL for 'owner', the other is FULL_CONTROL for 'both the object owner and the bucket owner'. Then I thought that the 'private' is only for object owner, not even for the bucket owner,hence the bucket owner can't access the object. It is not true...

Secondly, is there a way to stop browsing data from S3 console at all?
Thanks.

Comment: *"It is not true..."*  **Yes, it is.**  Remembering that the "owner" refers to the AWS Account (not a specific IAM user) who created the [ bucket | object ], please describe the scenario where you find this not to be true.

Comment: I was using super power root account to browse...I think that explains. For the account, who created the bucket but are not root account, there is a difference between these two canned ACLs. Thank you.

Comment: Account != user.  There is no "root account."  The root *user* and all the IAM *users* are all part of the same AWS *account*.  "Who" created the bucket refers to the AWS account the creating user is part of -- not individual users within that account.  The same goes for objects.  The owner of each is the *entire* AWS account -- not an individual user.

Comment: Thank you Michael!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object is an item in bucket.

*Access policy allows more permissions than ACL does, you use ACL to primarily grant basic read/write permissions, similar to file system permissions.*

For full-control a Canned ACL is bucket-owner-full-control:

*Both the object owner and the bucket owner get FULL_CONTROL over the object. If you specify this canned ACL when creating a bucket, Amazon S3 ignores it.*

private canned ACL applies to Bucket and object:

*Owner gets FULL_CONTROL. No one else has access rights (default).*

To Answer Second Question only way to stop browsing data from console is by logging in as an IAM user who does not have permission to s3, if you are logged in as root user **(NOT RECOMMENDED)** you will see all the AWS Resources in Console.

Hope this helps and for reference [read this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html).